# Галерея с оверлеем

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать галерею, или подскажите готовое решение с готовым функционалом как на скриншоте: http://prntscr.com/vmn588

Если подробнее, нужно сделать Grid сетку и в ней разместить изображения, по нажатию на которые будет открываться такой оверлей с возможностью переключаться между изображениями. Я нашёл парочку подходящих вариантов, но там настройка стилей, построение блоков и добавление самих изображений реализовано через JS, а хотелось бы размещать и стилизовать блоки (например добавлять описание под изображением) в HTML+CSS,
как тут, например: [image: Сетка изображений]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг кому-то пригодится подобное решение.
Готовая галерея FancyBox имеет кучу настроек, своего рода Swiper в мире галерей :D
Ссылка: [Перейти на сайт FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

посидел и подумал...
Вот принцип, как можно всё реализовать, почти готовое решение

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/css1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container-fluid">
        
        <div class="row">
           
            <div class="main col-lg-12">
                <div class="grid col-lg-3">
                    <a href="#mainimg"><img src="img/LogoWRP170x150.png"></img></a>
                    <div class="info">
                        <p>Описание:</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid col-lg-3">
                    <img src="img/LogoWRP170x150.png"></img>
                    <div class="info">
                        <p>Описание:</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" id="mainimg">
                        <div id="okno">
                            <img src="img/LogoWRP170x150.png"></img>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="grid col-lg-3">
                    <img src="img/LogoWRP170x150.png"></img>
                    <div class="info">
                        <p>Описание:</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid col-lg-3">
                    <img src="img/LogoWRP170x150.png"></img>
                    <div class="info">
                        <p>Описание:</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body
{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0;
}

.header
{
    background: wheat;
    height: 150px;
}
.main
{
    background: yellowgreen;
    height: 500px;
}
.grid
{
    
    background: yellow;
    height: 170px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.info
{
    background: blue;
    
}
#mainimg
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#okno 
{
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
border-radius: 200px;
color: #0000cc;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
}
#mainimg:target {display: block;}
```

Принцип работы:
https://ibb.co/JFj0mRz
https://ibb.co/bP40j7j

p.s Сорямба за кислотность, мне так удобнее блоки верстать.

Comment: Вы реализовали модальные окна, это не то, что нужно, увы)